# Data type to store a 33 digit wide number in C?

Tags: c, type-conversion

What is the data type that i should use to store a 33 digit wide number.
I am using `unsigned long long` but overflow occurs.How to deal with it?

Comment: Strictly speaking this is a subset. `char[33]` is a reasonable answer here,  but unsuited for arithmetic.

Comment: When you are saying "digit" what do you mean? Binary? Hexadecima? Decimal?

Comment: i am talking about decimal..

Answer (score 1):

`__int128` on GCC allows you to store numbers up to `170141183460469231731687303715884105727`, with 39 digits.

Comment: Isn't that `unsigned __int128`? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html

Comment: @pmg (1<<128) - 1 = (1<<0) + (1<<1) + (1<<2) + ... + (1<<127) = 340282366920938463463374607431768211455.

Comment: `1<<127` is UB for 128-bit wide signed integers

Comment: @pmg Argh, you're correct. In fact is (1<<127) - 1. Thanks

Comment: Remark: This is not portable; most other compilers do not provide a built in 128 bit type.

Comment: which header file do i need to include for that??? and how can i print this number using printf??